# I am unable to solve the functional equation, or find the necessary relation for this specific question.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, functional-equations

Given that $()$ is differentiable at least once,(for all 'x' belongs to set of real numbers) and satisfies the property,
$( + ) =  () +  () $, and **$′(0) = 2$**. *Show that **$′()= () + 2$** and that
$() = 2^$

I have tried substituting values for
$x$ and even got a relation between $f(2x)$ and $f(x)
$
$f(2x)=2(e^x)f(x)$

Yet I am unable to get how should I go about to prove the required.

Comment: $f(2x)=2exf(x)$ as per your question

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the math. Assuming all those $ex$ actually mean $e^x$, divide the equality by $e^{x+y}$ and notice that $f(x) / e^x$ satisfies the [Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Answer (score 2):

First, let's calculate $f'(x)$.
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(e^{x}f(h) + e^{h}f(x)) - f(x)}{h} \\
&= e^{x}f'(0) + f(x) \\
&=f(x) + 2e^{x}.
\end{align*}
Here, I use
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{h} - 1}{h} = 1.
$$
By solving the differential equation $f'(x) = f(x) + 2e^{x}$ and $f'(0) = 2$, we can obtain $f(x) = 2xe^{x}$.